# Items getting removed from underneath Favourites menu in Finder

Tags: macos, finder

Most of the link list of items I had under my sidebar in the finder have (every couple of months or so) been getting removed, leaving me to have to drag them back in again which is tedious and annoying.

I can't figure out why.

Comment: Are you sure they are not hidden accidentally.

Comment: What have you done/tried to remedy the situation?

Comment: They aren't hidden. When I posted this for example, there were only two folders, my home folder and downloads left on the side-bar.

I first had problems with this when I was using Dropbox to "backup" my folders, as it moved everything into dropbox's directories. However with the current situation I am not using Dropbox to backup anything. I haven't tried anything to remedy the situation because I have no idea what the issue could be.